# stop polling files when rabbitmq is down: spring integration

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp, spring-integration-sftp

I'm working on a project where we are polling files from a sftp server and streaming it out into a object on the rabbitmq queue. Now when the rabbitmq is down it still polls and deletes the file from the server and losses the file while sending it on queue when rabbitmq is down. I'm using **ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice** to remove the file on successful transformation. My code looks like this:

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
    factory.setHost(sftpProperties.getSftpHost());
    factory.setPort(sftpProperties.getSftpPort());
    factory.setUser(sftpProperties.getSftpPathUser());
    factory.setPassword(sftpProperties.getSftpPathPassword());
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
}    

@Bean
public SftpRemoteFileTemplate sftpRemoteFileTemplate() {
    return new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(sftpSessionFactory());
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = TransformerChannel.TRANSFORMER_OUTPUT, autoStartup = "false",
        poller = @Poller(value = "customPoller"))
public MessageSource<InputStream> sftpMessageSource() {
    SftpStreamingMessageSource messageSource = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(sftpRemoteFileTemplate,
            null);
    messageSource.setRemoteDirectory(sftpProperties.getSftpDirPath());
    messageSource.setFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(),
            "streaming"));
    messageSource.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"));
    return messageSource;
}    


@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = TransformerChannel.TRANSFORMER_OUTPUT,
        outputChannel = SFTPOutputChannel.SFTP_OUTPUT,
        adviceChain = "deleteAdvice")
public org.springframework.integration.transformer.Transformer transformer() {
    return new SFTPTransformerService("UTF-8");
}

@Bean
public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice deleteAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString(
                "@sftpRemoteFileTemplate.remove(headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + headers['file_remoteFile'])");
    advice.setPropagateEvaluationFailures(false);
    return advice;
}
```

I don't want the files to get removed/polled from the remote sftp server when the rabbitmq server is down. How can i achieve this ?

**UPDATE**

Apologies for not mentioning that I'm using spring cloud stream rabbit binder. And here is the transformer service:

```
public class SFTPTransformerService extends StreamTransformer {
public SFTPTransformerService(String charset) {
    super(charset);
}

@Override
protected Object doTransform(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
    String fileName = message.getHeaders().get("file_remoteFile", String.class);
    Object fileContents = super.doTransform(message);
    return new customFileDTO(fileName, (String) fileContents);
}
}
```

**UPDATE-2**
I added `TransactionSynchronizationFactory` on the customPoller as suggested. Now it doesn't poll file when rabbit server is down, but when the server is up, it keeps on polling the same file over and over again!! I cannot figure it out why? I guess i cannot use `PollerSpec` cause im on 4.3.2 version.

```
@Bean(name = "customPoller")
public PollerMetadata pollerMetadataDTX(StartStopTrigger startStopTrigger,
                                        CustomTriggerAdvice customTriggerAdvice) {
    PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
    pollerMetadata.setAdviceChain(Collections.singletonList(customTriggerAdvice));
    pollerMetadata.setTrigger(startStopTrigger);
    pollerMetadata.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(Long.valueOf(sftpProperties.getMaxMessagePoll()));
    ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor syncProcessor =
            new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();
    syncProcessor.setBeanFactory(applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
    syncProcessor.setBeforeCommitChannel(
            applicationContext.getBean(TransformerChannel.TRANSFORMER_OUTPUT, MessageChannel.class));
    syncProcessor
            .setAfterCommitChannel(
                    applicationContext.getBean(SFTPOutputChannel.SFTP_OUTPUT, MessageChannel.class));
    syncProcessor.setAfterCommitExpression(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(
            "@sftpRemoteFileTemplate.remove(headers['file_remoteDirectory'] + headers['file_remoteFile'])"));
    DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory defaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory =
            new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(syncProcessor);
    pollerMetadata.setTransactionSynchronizationFactory(defaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory);
    return pollerMetadata;
}
```

I don't know if you need this info but my `CustomTriggerAdvice` and `StartStopTrigger` looks like this :

```
@Component
public class CustomTriggerAdvice extends AbstractMessageSourceAdvice {

@Autowired private StartStopTrigger startStopTrigger;

@Override
public boolean beforeReceive(MessageSource<?> source) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> result, MessageSource<?> source) {
    if (result == null) {
        if (startStopTrigger.getStart()) {
            startStopTrigger.stop();
        }
    } else {
        if (!startStopTrigger.getStart()) {
            startStopTrigger.stop();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

}


public class StartStopTrigger implements Trigger {

private PeriodicTrigger startTrigger;
private boolean start;

public StartStopTrigger(PeriodicTrigger startTrigger, boolean start) {
    this.startTrigger = startTrigger;
    this.start = start;
}

@Override
public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
    if (!start) {
        return null;
    }
    start = true;
    return startTrigger.nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
}

public void stop() {
    start = false;
}

public void start() {
    start = true;
}

public boolean getStart() {
    return this.start;
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like you don't `start()` your `startStopTrigger` in case of `if (!startStopTrigger.getStart()) {`. You still call there `stop()`

Comment: I don't believe that you need `beforeCommitChannel` and `afterCommitChannel` on your processor. The point is to remove file only after successful send to the AMQP. This TX advice is really applied fully to your entire process starting with the `@InboundChannelAdapter` and ending in the `AmqpOutboundEndpoint`

Comment: @ArtemBilan I do start the ```startStopTrigger``` via rest call. Here is what it looks like :rtemBilan

Comment: `private void setSourcePollingChannelAdapter() {
            sourcePollingChannelAdapter.stop();
            applicationContext.getBean("startStopTrigger", StartStopTrigger.class).start();
            sourcePollingChannelAdapter.start();
    }`

Comment: Well, you have changed something else in your configuration. The `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` does the trick do not poll the same file again...

Comment: @ArtemBilan can you tell whether the `setAfterCommitExpression` is being set correctly !? Cause im able to solve the repeating polling file issue, but the file is not getting deleted from the server.

Comment: You have to call `afterPropertiesSet()` on the `syncProcessor`

Comment: Also you can turn on DEBUG logging level for the `org.springframework.integration` to trace in logs how your message travels and what and with what is called there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, would be great to see what your `SFTPTransformerService` and determine how it is possible to perform an `onSuccessExpression` when there should be an exception in case of down broker.

You also should not only throw an exception do not perform delete, but consider to add a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` to re-send the file to the RabbitMQ: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#retry-advice

**UPDATE**

So, well, since Gary guessed that you use Spring Cloud Stream to send message to the Rabbit Binder after your internal process (very sad that you didn't share that information originally), you need to take a look to the Binder error handling on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_retry_with_the_rabbitmq_binder

And that is true that `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` is applied only for the `SFTPTransformerService` and nothing more. The downstream error (in the Binder) is not included in this process already.

**UPDATE 2**

Yeah... I think Gary is right, and we don't have choice unless configure a `TransactionSynchronizationFactory` on the `customPoller` level instead of that `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`: ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice .

The `DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory`  can be configured with the `ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor`, which has similar goal as the mentioned `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`, but on the transaction level which will include your process starting with the SFTP Channel Adapter and ending on the Rabbit Binder level with the send to AMQP attempts.

See Reference Manual for more information: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html#transaction-synchronization.

The point with the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` (and any `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice`) that they have a boundary only around `handleRequestMessage()` method, therefore only during the component they are declared.

Comment: The advice only advises the transformer; successful transformation will take the onSuccess route. I presume the `SFTPOutputChannel.SFTP_OUTPUT` is a Spring Cloud Stream binding? If so, an error there is too late for this advice to catch.

Comment: Ugh, Gary! Looks like I need vacation. That's fully unclear by the question that there is Spring Cloud Stream involved... Very clever of you to get that all :-).

Comment: Not that smart - his/her original question was in the SCSt room on gitter. A [pseudo transaction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html#pseudo-transactions) is probably the best fit for this use case.

Comment: Right, but that wasn't clear there and it isn't here. Why it is so hard to mention Rabbit Binder as a transport?.. Or this is not my domain any more otherwise...

Comment: Actually that link (retry) is for the consumer bindings. For producer bindings, the standard [boot rabbitmq template retry properties apply](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) (scroll down to the rabbitmq properties). BTW, it looks like we don't have a good example of transaction synchronization using Java configuration.

Comment: `public PollerSpec transactionSynchronizationFactory()` is there for you. Also the `TransactionSynchronizationFactory` is a part of `PollerMetadata` which can be used from the `@Poller(value)` and it is mentioned in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell and AtremBilan ... i will try the suggestions out and will post back soon !!! **(NOTE: i've added transformer service)**

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell So i added the  `TransactionSynchronizationFactory ` that you  guys suggested but im still having some problem with it...can you guys tell what im doing wrong!?